# What are the values of $m$ and $n$?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

The equation $x3+mx^2+2x+n=0$, where $m$ and $n$ are
real numbers, admits $1 + i$ as a root. What are the values of $m$
and $n$?

Comment: Hint: look up Vieta’s formulas.

Comment: Hint: All non-real roots of polynomials with real coefficients come in complex conjugate pairs (e.g., see [Complex conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem)).

Comment: Would $1-i$ also be a root?

Comment: Hint: $(1+i)^3+m(1+i)^2+2(1+i)+n=0+0i$

Answer (score 1):

According to Wolfy
(or by hand),

$(1+i)^3+m*(1+i)^2+2*(1+i)+n
= i (2m+4) + n
$
so
$n=0, m=-2
$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\overline{x^3+mx^2+2x+n}=0$$ its
$$\overline{x}^3+m\overline{x}^2+2\overline{x}+n=0,$$
we see the $1-i$ is a root of the equation.

Id est, $x^3+mx^2+2x+n$ is divisible by $$(x-1-i)(x-1+i),$$ which is
$$x^2-2x+2$$ and we obtain:
$$x^3+mx^2+2x+n=x(x^2-2x+2)+(m+2)x^2+n,$$ which gives $m=-2$ and $n=0.$